# Mirroring effect in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is it possible to create a mirroring effect in Flex4 at runtime? (load picture and create a mirrored part of that image).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a reflection of a `DisplyObject` by `scaleX = -1` (in a vertical mirror) or `scaleY = -1` (for a horizontal one)
another way is to draw graphics you want to reflect as a `BitmapData` so that it'd be possible to implement any pixelwise reflecting algorithm you can imagine